# PECL install imagick using wrong php version

Tags: centos, php, centos6, pecl

I'm running a server on centos 6.8, and running a magento 2 site on this.
The default version of php is 5.3.3, however the site itself is running on 5.6.5.

The latest upgrade to magento2 requires the imagick extension installed and included in php.ini, so i attempted `sudo pecl install imagick` which returns requires 5.4.0 and greater.

Is there a way to run this command and specify what version of php I wish to use?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you installed php 5.6.5 from a third party repository. If you are lucky this repository might contains imagick binaries.

Try this

```
yum search imagick
```

and install the package if it is available with

```
yum install package-name
```

Comment: I need it to be available to add to php.ini

Comment: if php 5.6.5 is installed through package manager (yum) and you also install imagick from the same repository then yum will do this automatically.

Comment: I already have done this via yum (a few days ago), and as mentioned it hasn't updated the php.ini.
I've restarted the server since then, and the issue persists.

Comment: OK let's do something else. Please provide the result of the following commands:

rpm -qa |grep php5

and then use repoquery -i package-name to detect from which repositories comes the installed php.

Comment: The repo for `more-php56-php-mcrypt-5.6.5-2.el6.x86_64` (one of the returned packages) was `remi-php56more-epel-6-x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me.
In my case is php70.

```
cd ~
export PATH=/usr/local/php70/bin:$PATH
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Check again with command 'php -v'.
Refer [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214202148-How-do-I-change-the-PHP-version-my-shell-uses-) for more information.